# Adding button to table javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web

I'm trying to add 'Download' button into a table, but some of the buttons return `null`, and than I get this error:

> "Cannot set property 'onclick' of null".

JS CODE:

```
 var table = $('#dataTables-example').DataTable();
 ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
 snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
  var childData = childSnapshot.val();
  var number = childData.ParNumber;
  var numOfTr = childData.NumOfTry;
  var startTime = childData.startTime;
  numberofbutton = Math.random();
  table.row.add( [
      coursrNum,
      number,
      numOfTr,
      startTime,
    '<button id =' +numberofbutton+'>Download File</button>'
  ] ).draw( false );
     var button = document.getElementById(numberofbutton);
     button.onclick = function(){ myScript(number+'_'+numOfTr)};
    });

});
```

Comment: Shouldn't your string be  `'<button id=' + numberofbutton + '>Download File</button>'`?

Comment: @Kobe That what i did, still not working...

Comment: Using `Math.random()` for IDs is icky. Most likely why you get the issue. You can just use sequential numbers or even create the button, attach a click handler and then pass it. Not sure if the latter is supported but it's likely that it is.

Comment: @VLAZ I changed it to a small number and it's still not working.

Comment: @shirlyGrinblat wow, I keep forgetting how annoying the DataTables API can be. Apparently you cannot add an HTML element. Not unless the whole *row* is an HTML element. I have removed my answer in light of that. I will re-post if I find a better alternative.